# RawPy - figuring out the whether the filter array/image type of ARW (raw-sensor) image is "Bayer"

Tags: python-2.7, image-processing

I'm using Sony camera (model: RX100-VI)
I process the ARW files (whose I get as outputsfrom the camera) using the package "RawPy".
after erforming the next lines I get numpy image:

```
import rawpy as rp
r1 = rp.imread("DSC00025.ARW") 
im1 = r1.raw_image_visible
```

I want to know if the filter array is Bayer. Do Ih have any way to ensure it?
Thanks =]

Comment: Do you mean `r1.color_desc` which shows as `RGBG`?

Comment: Or you can check the dimensionality `r1.raw_image.ndim` is 2 as it will be for Bayer images, whereas it would be 3 for Foveon sensors.

Comment: Hi @MarkSetchell.
indeed. `r1.color_desc` shows `RGBG` and `r1.raw_image.ndim` show 2.
in addition, `r1.raw_pattern` shows `array([[0, 1], [3, 2]], dtype=uint8)`.
so can I discuss it is bayer array for sure?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but I'd go with that assumption until proved incorrect.